# How to serialize form in ajax and save data in database with laravel?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a form in which I user can insert multiple inputs fields and save to database using ajax
Here are the inputs,

I'm trying to send a serialized form to my database. My question is that when I serialize the form, use JQuery to attach it to a hidden input field, and then send the the form and some other information to the database, the rest of the information is reaching the database but I still have a blank in where the serialized form is. If anyone could point out where I went wrong and/or explain how this should be done I'd be very grateful! Thank you very much!

blade

```
<form method="post" id="form-job-store">
    <input type="hidden" name="url" value="{{ route('job.store') }}">
    @csrf
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
            <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                <label for="history">history</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="history" name="history">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                <label for="post_title">post_title</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="post_title" name="post_title">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btn-job-submit"><i class="fas fa-plus fa-xs"></i> Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
<form>
```

script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btn-job-submit').on('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var formData = new FormData($('#form-job-store')[0]);
        let url = $('#form-job-store :input')[0].getAttribute('value');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url,
            data:  $(formData).serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            },
        });
    });
});
```

web.php

```
Route::resource('job', 'JobController');
```

JobController.php

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $job = Job::create([
        'user_id' => auth()->id(),
        'post_title' => $request->post_title,
        'history' => $request->history,
    ]);
    return response()->json($job);
}
```

Comment: You dont need to serialise it, formdata (look it up) already did that

Comment: SO try `data:  formData,`

Comment: This code creates a new row in the table (database). But it does not fill the information.

Comment: Debug: Step1:: Did you try a `dd($request);` to see whats in the `$request`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn-job-submit').on('submit', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url:'{{route('job.store')}}',
            method:"POST",
            data:new FormData(this),
            dataType:'JSON',
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            success:function(data){

            }
       })
   })
})
```